# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: clipboard

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using https://github.com/zhuowenli/vue-clipboards. But when i tried this it doesn't work. I'm new to vue and nuxt js. and there is an error on the console that says `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: clipboard`. BTW i have already installed clipboard.

Template

```
<button v-clipboard='message'>Copy</button>
```

Script

```
import VueClipboards from 'vue-clipboards'
export default {
  components: { VueClipboards },
  data () {
    return {
      message: 'asdad'
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

This same issue is mentioned here:
https://github.com/Inndy/vue-clipboard2/issues/4

You can solve it adding the component in the main.js file. By doing that, you are making it global.

https://vuejsfeed.com/blog/copy-texts-to-clipboard-using-vue-clipboard2

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

[I got the same error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngd9g.png)

Resolved it by

```
import VueClipboard from 'vue-clipboard2';
Vue.use(VueClipboard);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import Vue & use it

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import vueClipboards from 'vue-clipboards'

Vue.use(vueClipboards)

...
```

Don't forget to remove the `components: { VueClipboards },`

Answer (score 0):

import vueClipboards from 'vue-clipboards'

Vue.use(vueClipboards)

Import it to the main component and it works for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Even before importing it to the current component I removed the  `"components: { VueClipboards }"` but still it was not working. I just imported it to component instead of importing it to the Main.js file.